# Cucumber wait for page to finish page load

Tags: ruby, cucumber, capybara

What's the best way to force cucumber to wait for page to finish loading of the page?

Im logging into my website and on the first page I have a string "User profile"

page.should have_css(".user-profile")
page.should have_content("User profile")

Sometimes logging takes to long and test fails on this step page.should have_content("User profile") how to to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Try to set a different wait time https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#asynchronous-javascript-ajax-and-friends

```
Capybara.default_wait_time = 5
```